# Ubuntu 19.04 stuck on Hyper-V XRDP login screen

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, hyper-v, login-screen

I can get to the login, from the drop-down I chose Xorg and enter the username and password. It then hangs for 2-3 minutes on a turquoise screen like below (without the dialog).. then the dialog pops up. If I hit ok, it takes me back to the beginning (xorg + username + password).

How can I fix it? I can't seem to find a way to bring up a terminal or log in at all..

It worked fine earlier. I was coding some OpenGL stuff and after I rebooted and came back, now I have this problem. Nothing other than `mesa-dev-common, xlib, g++, clang++, Codeblocks` has been installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.. Albeit not in the way I really wanted to.
What happened was the OpenGL program I wrote would save a copy of the backbuffer as a .bmp file every frame..

So my desktop got filled with Bitmap images and ran out of harddisk space..
I only discovered this problem after I converted the VHDX to VHD and used 7zip to unzip the entire thing since I couldn't get it to mount.

Now I see over 2000 images on the Desktop. I could have expanded the VM's size but I didn't know what the problem was until after.

Hope that helps anyone having a similar issue :l Check the HDD space first!